# Video streaming crashing after an hour

Tags: raspbian, streaming-video, pi-zero-w, crash

I would like to use a Raspberry Pi Zero to stream video from the camera.
I have WiFi and ssh setup, and all works well.

However, it appears that after an hour or so, the Raspberry stops streaming video and I can't reach it via ssh anymore. It does not respond to ping either.

I can't figure out why and what is going on. I wonder if anybody else
has experienced this and/or know what is causing this.

I have Raspbian light installed, and all upgrades and updates, as well
as rpi-update.

Comment: I should have added, that when I say crash, I mean I can not access it at all (ping/ssh).

Comment: Compute intensive loops can cause over heating or memory leaks.

Comment: Observe the streaming process' memory size over time. Does it grow? When it reaches a set limit, it will be killed.

Comment: Is there any traces in the log files/ `/var/log/...` at the times when it stop streaming?

Comment: The question may be, can the pi w handle the throughput? I use a rPi 2 to stream 6 cameras, but I can't over wifi. It needs to be connected to Ethernet.

Comment: I agree with looking at log files after reboot.  Unfortunately, Linux crashes may not flush the last few messages, so you don't see what you need to see.  To debug this problem, I suggest you connect a serial port to the rPi and configure it for login and as a system console (so kernel messages are displayed).  When the system stops working, you can determine if Linux is running and you may see some helpful messages in the terminal emulator connected to the serial port.